# Determining Chances of Last Digit Matches in a Polyhedral Dice Pool

Tags: dice

In a pool of polyhedral dice (made up of $4$ to $6$ $2$-sided, $4$-sided, $6$-sided, $8$-sided, $10$-sided, and $12$-sided dice) how do you determine the chances of matching the last digit rolled on a $20$-sided die?

I am interested in determining the chances of one or more of the pool results matching a simultaneously-thrown d$20$'s final digit. (*i.e. a "$1$" on a die matching the "$1$" or "$11$" on the d$20$, or a "$10$" on a d$12$ matching the "$10$" or "$20$" on the d$20$*)

Specific points of interest for me include:

1. What are the chances of $0, 1, 2, \dots$ matches?
2. Does an increase in the number of sides of the dice in the pool translate into greater chances of matches?
3. Is there a difference between a d$10$ and a d$12$ in terms of how likely one or the other is to generate a match to the d$20$?

Comment: For 1. the python source (and the result of exhaustive search and summation) is [here](https://tio.run/##fZDBboMwEETP8VfsBeElFsU0ShASp0r9gFwjDghCawI2sk2lquq3UxtQovbQm3f2zezI46d9V/I5G/U8i2FU2oKwV22V6g1ptRqgVn1/ra1Q0sBGvKhJOmjdt7r6vX3dBKgMnElTfIk8gVZpECDkIz0etWqm2lJdybcr5Qmy9XVC/Cb/8NFlczC557gkS09eUnZgR5YxnjCeliXmZFcXW1faBXxt0S2pSHZ@uLEPP9axOzMY6i275kKdjOW@4BvkkXtLj4jWiVLZxeuF1ZSsplELaWnIIIw7JSQNgyaHwISBQ4ixmp6pmQZKqWA39BENVLIBF@GFEtzJBB8/dr@MLI0O0THKIp5EPMWn86ISBPKn5smJOM8/). For 3. d12 is more likely to produce $1$ and $2$ than d10. The chances of match are the same -- $\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: The final digit is the one that must match. A 10 matches a 10 or a 20, as the final digit is 0. A 1 matches a 1 or an 11, as the final digit is 1. I am unsure how to make that clearer, given that I explicitly state this...